# how to go new line in cell in table in phpword?

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

I want to create a word file `.docx` from my data that exist in database.
To do this job I am using a phpword 0.12.0 .
I need to draw a table to place data inside it. After that I need to fetch every row from table in database to automatically go in cell of new line.
I can do this job with

```
$section->addTextBreak();
```

but without table, now how can I do this job in cell inside the table?
I am using below code, but it doesn't work.

```
$area=array();
$axis=array();
$topic=array();
$table->addRow(900);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('test1'), $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('test2'), $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('test3'), $fontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $styleCell)->addText(htmlspecialchars('test4'), $fontStyle);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
      $table->addRow();
      $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($topic{$i}),array('name' => 'Segoe UI Semilight'));
      $table->addCell(3000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($axis{$i}),array('rtl' => true,'name' => 'Segoe UI Semilight'));
      $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($area{$i}),array('rtl' => true,'name' => 'Segoe UI Semilight'));
      $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($i),array('rtl' => true,'name' => 'Segoe UI Semilight'));
}
```

Comment: so what is exactly the problem? The above code seems to work fine - if you have some actual arrays with 4 or more items for the area, axis and topic arrays that is - it creates a table with the test cells on first row and new rows in each for loop. Do you have some problems with the database query or with creating the table contents?

Answer (score 7):

You must first create a cell object, and then use addText

```
    $c1=$table->addCell(2000);
    $c1->addText("Cell 1");
    $c1->addText("New line");
```

Comment: add a bit of explanation

Answer (score 1):

As @Milaza pointed out, you can

```
// define the cell
$cell = $table->addCell(2000);

// add one line
$cell->addText("Cell 1");

// then add another one
$cell->addText("New line");
```

I think this is annoying, since I have to break a line of text into multiple lines and I have a lot cell text to break. So I created(2016-11-08) a method in `PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Element/Cell.php`:

```
/**
 * Add multi-line text
 *
 * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Cell
 */
public function addMultiLineText($text, $fStyle = null, $pStyle = null)
{
    // break from line breaks
    $strArr = explode('\n', $text);

    // add text line together
    foreach ($strArr as $v) {
        $this->addText($v, $fStyle, $pStyle);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It breaks text string from `\n` mark.

So when you are adding a cell, you can use it like:

```
// "$fStyle", "$pStyle" are the old "$fStyle", "$pStyle" you pass to old "addText" method
$table->addCell(2000)->addMultiLineText("Line 1\nLine 2", $fStyle, $pStyle);
```

The output will look like:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

If you do not want to modify the source code, I have already added it in here.

https://github.com/shrekuu/PHPWord

https://packagist.org/packages/shrekuu/phpword

You can just install this one by running:

```
composer require shrekuu/phpword
```